# Lifetime of Nested Execution Contexts

Tags: javascript, scope, executioncontext

I am following along with an [article on javascript closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/).

In trying to learn the particulars of execution context, I came across a result that surprised me.

```
var globalVar = 'g';
var inner;
var outer = function() {
  var outerVar = 'o';
  inner = function() {
    var innerVar = 'i';
    console.log(innerVar, outerVar, globalVar);
  }
}

outer()
inner() // Q: What does this log out?
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6zvsh/

This actually outputs `i o g`.

I expected to see `i undefined g`.

Here is my understanding of the process. I would like to understand my error:

1. `inner` is declared as a property on the global object and the value is set to `undefined`
2. `outer` is invoked.
3. An execution context is created for `outer` whose scope chain includes `outerVar` and the global object.
4. The value of the `inner` property on the global object is assigned a reference to the function definition.
5. The execution context for `outer` finishes. (the related scopes are removed? marked for GC?)
6. `inner` is invoked.
7. An execution context is created whose scope chain includes `innerVar` and the global object.
8. `outerVar` is not found in scope

Can someone please explain why `outerVar` is defined?

Comment: You just have discovered closures! [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: This could be the answer, too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11148475/111243

Comment: That comment might be a bit more pandering than necessary, @Bergi. I think this is a question about some nuance between invocation and declaration that I don't understand, rather than needing a general overview. I'm reading a few different overviews, just the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function is created, it references its surrounding execution context as the scope, creating a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) for it.

Let's step through it:

> 1. `inner` is declared as a property on the global object and the value is set to `undefined`

1.5. the `outer` function is created, referencing the global scope as its parent scope

> 2. `outer` is invoked.
>
> 3. An execution context is created for `outer` whose scope <s>chain</s> includes `outerVar` and the global object.

…because the chain link of the new execution context references the parent scope of `outer`, which is (assigned in 1.5) the global scope.  `outerVar` is a variable in this new execution context.

> 4. The value of the `inner` property on the global object is assigned a reference to the function definition.

…and the function's parent scope is set to the execution context of `outer`.

> 5. The execution context for `outer` finishes. <s>(the related scopes are removed? marked for GC?)</s>

…but is not garbage-collected because it is still referenced as the parent scope of the `inner` function which is still living (not garbage).

> 6. `inner` is invoked.
>
> 7. An execution context is created whose scope <s>chain</s> includes `innerVar` and the global object.

The new execution context has a scope chain link to `inner`s parent context, which is the execution context created above for the `outer` call (which has the chain link to the global scope). `innerVar` is a variable in this new execution context.

> 8. `outerVar` is <s>not</s> found in scope

…chain.

Comment: Awesome. I think the key thing I missed is the timing of assigning the scope to the function object. I summed it up like this: Q: Why does it have access to `outerVar`? A: Because when `outer` is run, a function object is created for `inner` whose [[scope]] is assigned the value of outer's execution context. The outer's execution context's scope is a chain which contains the Activation/Variable object (arguments, outerVar) and the global object. Because the GC can see a reference from the global `inner` property to the executionContext scope of outer, that scope is maintained.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only I didn't focus on using the correct terminology (didn't have the time to cite the [relevant spec section](http://es5.github.io/#x10.3)), please excuse if I have mixed the terms "scope" and "execution context".